# The directory public://xmlsitemap was not found or is not writable by the server

Tags: 8, caching, xml-sitemap

I have just installed [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) on a EC2 drupal 8 instance. I am seeing the following error message in the admin report status page:

```
XML sitemap cache directory
Not found or not writable
The directory public://xmlsitemap was not found or is not writable by the server.
See http://drupal.org/node/34025 for more information.
```

The provided link is broken. I have done some reading and created a `/xmlsitemap` directory in `/var/www/html` (which is the root of my drupal installation). I `chmod` it to give `rwx` access to everyone (`a+`).

But, the issue remains. I cannot generate the cache files.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't the `public://xmlsitemap` point to `sites/default/files/xmlsitemap` in this case or is this only true for drupal 7?

Comment: @Cyclone is correct, that is the default path for public://

Comment: You should also be able to check the path through running the following drush command from the root of your installation: `drush vget file_public_path` or running the following query against your database `SELECT * FROM variable WHERE name = 'file_public_path'`

Comment: I get a `Command variable-get requires Drupal core version 6 or 7 to run.` when running Drush. I am checking for the query solution.

Comment: Just to resolve the above issue, under drupal 8 you should instead be able to use `drush config-get file_public_path` to get the path to the public files folder.

Comment: Just tried, I get `Config file_public_path does not exist in active configuration.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `file_public_path` value from the `/admin/config/media/file-system` page. It was set to `sites/default/files`, relative to the installation path.

I checked permissions and noticed some writting permissions were missing (the directory was already created). I `sudo chmod a+w xmlsitemap/` and that solved the issue.